# Behaviour of enum in c#

Tags: c#, enums

```
 class MainClass
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Fruits f =Fruits.Banana;
        Console.WriteLine("Fruit={0}",f);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private enum Fruits
    {
        Banana=0,
        Apple=0,
        Orange=0,
        Cherries
    }

}
```

The above code gives output: `Fruit=Apple`

If I change the value of Banana to anything other than 0 within enum, the output is Banana. My question is why in the first case, the output is `Apple` and not `Orange` or `Banana` itself?

Comment: I'll answer with a question. What is the meaning of having three different items in an Enum have the same value?

Comment: I think they are basing it alphabetically.

Comment: just for checking its behaviour, I am still in the preliminary stage of learning c#, just having fun with the code.

Comment: _anything other than 0 within enum, the output is Banana_ - I doubt that, please check.

Comment: Sure, but when you do something like that, are you surprised that the results are somewhat strange?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: can you please say which value other than 0 is not giving a Banana?

Comment: Well, `1` would give `cherries` (I think) and `2` will just give `2`

Comment: But this simply is abuse / misunderstading of enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, an enum is very like a `struct` with a single internal field - having the same type as the base type for the enum (here, `int`), which stores the value.

That's it, so far as an enum is concerned. It has no storage for anything else - it does not know *how* it was constructed - whether by using a named value from the enumeration, or by casting from the base type, or any other means.

As such, when you ask for a string representation, it has no further information to go on than to take the numeric value and attempt to find a name among its enumeration members that matches that value.

<strike>I'm not sure whether it's *defined* which value will be selected if multiple members have the same numeric value, but it's got to pick *something*, and it at least appears to be *consistent*.</strike>

---

In fact, [`Enum.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx) says:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

Comment: surely it makes sense. I should then expect any one of Banana, Apple or Orange to appear as output, I have run the code multiple times, but each time it produces Apple.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee - it will, *probably*, always return `Apple` at the moment. But the warning is there to say to not *assume* that this will always be the case - maybe in the future they'll change how enums work deep down in the CLR, and it will start returning random values, or always `Orange`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even doing something like that? Anyways, it's because internally, `enum`s with the same value are chosen alphabetically.

Comment: Do you have any references which specifies this? I have tried the code and know that this is the behavior, but could not find any related documentation